# Get Value from Json by Key

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a json response as shown below

```json
{
    "SNGS": {
        "$": {
            "xmlns": "csng",
            "xmlns:ns2": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        },
        "Defect": [{
            "$": {
                "id": "DCV19294",
                "ns2:href": "https://mywebsite.com/api/beta//bug/DCSV19294"
            },
            "Field": [{
                "_": "4",
                "$": {
                    "name": "Severity"
                }
            }, {
                "_": "N",
                "$": {
                    "name": "Status"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I am trying to get value of below keys:
1] id
2] status

> I tried to parse json & get value by key using below code but I am getting undefined in alert. WHY?

```js
const data='{"SNGS":{"$":{"xmlns":"csng","xmlns:ns2":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"},"Defect":[{"$":    {"id":"DCV19294","ns2:href":"https://mywebsite.com/api/beta//bug/DCSV19294"},"Field":[{"_":"4","$":{"name":"Severity"}},{"_":"N","$":{"name":"Status"}}]}]}}'

const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(parsedData.id);
console.log(parsedData.Status);
```

I want to get id i.e.DCV19294 & status i.e. N from above Json. please help.

Comment: There is only one property on the top level, `SNGS` - so you need to access that first of all. Then you need to access `Defect` below that. And since that is an array, you will then either have to loop over that, or access specific entries directly via their index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know the logic behind the extraction of data. You could access it directly like below. However there could be a better logic if you explain it a bit more.

```js
const data='{"SNGS":{"$":{"xmlns":"csng","xmlns:ns2":"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"},"Defect":[{"$":    {"id":"DCV19294","ns2:href":"https://mywebsite.com/api/beta//bug/DCSV19294"},"Field":[{"_":"4","$":{"name":"Severity"}},{"_":"N","$":{"name":"Status"}}]}]}}'

const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

const id = parsedData.SNGS.Defect[0].$.id
const name = parsedData.SNGS.Defect[0].Field[1]._

console.log(id, name)
```

Comment: perfect!!! just did 1 change in your code to get exact status:
var name = parsedData.SNGS.Defect[0].Field[1]._;